# Setting a max iOS deployment target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm experiencing a weird bug at the moment where background / silent push notifications aren't being processed by devices that are on the latest iOS version - 15.3

Running the app on older OS versions 15.1 / 15.2.1 I was receiving the console log info correctly.

Nothing has changed from the backend sending the notification to the devices, and is shown to work with the older iOS devices.

I was wondering since this seems to be an issue only on that version of iOS, are we able to set the max supported deployment target?

So I would say this is working, but if you're on iOS 15.3 then there are no updates available to you.

I searched around but most of the results talk about either setting a min deployment target or using the available inline code..

---

Re: the push notification

The app *does* register with the backend service, and when pushed the logs detail that the APNs was successful. Triggering it on two devices side-by-side with different OS versions causes one to work and the other to not..

Comment: How did you manage to fix this? @markb

Comment: @Saif - I dont think its possible. you could do some hacky things like sitting the whole app inside an @available() but I dont know how well it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not reasonable because in Xcode you can setting the minimum iOS deployment